# How Thymeleaf know which endpoint to use?

Tags: java, thymeleaf

The "/ add-person" method performs redirect to /people. How does Thymeleaf know which endpoint to redirect to? How do redirect to a POST method?

```
@GetMapping("/people")
public String getPeopleGet(Model model) {
    return "people";
}

@PostMapping("/people")
public String getPeoplePost(Model model) {
    return "people";
}

@GetMapping("/add-person")
public String addPerson() {
    return "redirect:/person";
}
```

Comment: Thymeleaf isn't involved at all in redirects; those happen at the HTTP layer.

Comment: And how to call the post method?

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to call the `POST` of `/people` and you are using a `<form>`, then set the `method` attribute to `post`.

Comment: But it is possible to do this directly form Java class?